# Case-insensitve string comparison

Tags: swift, unicode, string-comparison

Is there any difference between the following ways of comparing strings without case in Swift?

```
let equal = str1.lowercased() == str2.lowercased() // or uppercased()
```

vs:

```
let equal = str1.caseInsensitiveCompare(str2) == .orderedSame
```

Is there any case in any language where one returns an incorrect result? *I'm more interested in Unicode correctness than performance.*

Comment: The call to `caseInsensitiveCompare` ultimately falls down to [CFString's CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/e48175bca494b8a6dc22079af42dbd66c0805eda/CoreFoundation/String.subproj/CFString.c#L2553) with `kCFCompareCaseInsensitive`. You might look at logic around there for insight.

Answer (score 1):

The `caseInsensitiveCompare` can be far more efficient (though I'd be shocked if it's observable in normal every day usage). And, IMHO, it's more intuitive regarding the intent.

Regarding "unicode correctness", I guess it depends upon what you mean. For example, comparing "Straße" to "strasse", `caseInsensitiveCompare` will say they're the same, whereas `lowercased` approach will not (though `uppercased` will).

But if you compare `"\u{E9}"` to `"\u{65}\u{301}"` in Swift 4 (see the unicode correctness discussion in WWDC 2017 [What's New in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/)), they both correctly recognize that those are `é` and will say they're the same, even though those two strings have different numbers of unicode scalars.

Answer (score 0):

Both do the same thing, `lowercased()` or `uppercased()` won't affect the Unicode characters so the end result will always be matching to other string when you compare.

These methods support all types of special characters including emoji icons.

Same goes with `caseInsensitiveCompare`; this too will ignore special characters, symbols etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't affect the Unicode characters"? For example, `é` will convert to `É` by `uppercased`. Also, what do you mean by "will ignore special characters, symbols, etc."? I don't believe that `caseInsensitiveCompare` ignores any characters, so I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. You're not saying that they won't affect the unicode characters themselves (because they will), but merely that the "end result will always match" as one would expect. Very good.